# Need help flipping photo 180 degrees

Tags: python

I am trying to flip this picture I have picked 180 degrees so it appears upside down. I keep getting an error message that says:

> getPixel(picture,x,y): x (= 222) is less than 0 or bigger than the width (= 221)The error was:Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

Here is my code:

```
 def flip(picture):
h=getHeight(picture)
w=getWidth(picture)
new_pic=makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
targetX = 0
for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(picture)):
  targetY = 0
  for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(picture)):
    color = getColor(getPixel(picture,sourceX,sourceY))
    setColor(getPixel(new_pic,targetX,targetY), color)
    targetY = targetY + 1
  targetX = targetX + 1
show(picture)
show(new_pic)
return new_pic
```

Comment: I dunno, but it's really weird that once you seem to pass variables to `getPixel` in the order of `pic`,`x`,`y` and a line below `pic`,`y`,`x` o.ó.

Comment: so i flipped that and it just gives me the same image. it hasnt flipped.

Comment: Does setColor(getPixel(new_pic,w-1-sourceX,h-1-sourceY), color) work?

Comment: Well, I didn't analyze the code. Maybe it was swapped because you want to flip picture, so you changed the order. However, `targetX` to me should be an `x` coord. Also, now you seem like you didn't write the code, I just said it looks weird, you should be able to tell if it's correct logic, not randomly swap order of variables to see if it works. That is [shotgun debigging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging). It would also be nice if you at least provided something to reproduce the problem when you just effortlessly come with "Here's my code and error, what's wrong?" question.

Comment: brm your way worked. Thank you. and Luk32 i am new to coding and I simply coded the way my professor gave me and it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your code is swapping the x and y values of the original picture. So the resulting picture will be a diagonal reflection of the original, not a rotation. Therefore, the resulting picture's width must be the original picture's height and the resulting picture's height must be the original picture's width. Since you use the original width and height for the new picture, if one value is larger than the other (not a square picture) you will go outside the picture.

To flip the picture like intended, instead of swapping the x and y values, subtract the current x and y value from the width and height respectively minus 1. So it should look like this:

```
def flip(picture):
    h=getHeight(picture)
    w=getWidth(picture)
    new_pic=makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            color = getColor(getPixel(picture,x,y))
            setColor(getPixel(new_pic,(w-x-1),(h-y-1)), color)
    show(picture)
    show(new_pic)
    return new_pic
```

I've also added a few optimizations, such as not calling getWidth and getHeight multiple times